# Construct SELECT WHERE query with array_keys and array_values in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I was able to use array_keys and array_values to do an `INSERT` for MySQL:

```
$columns = implode(", ", array_keys($cmd_array));
$escaped_values = array_map( $dbc->real_escape_string, array_values($cmd_array));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
$query = "INSERT INTO cmd ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
```

Is there a feature to do the same thing for `SELECT WHERE` like this?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  cmd WHERE ($columns) = ($values)";
```

Comment: You have to specify more than one condition using the `AND` or the `OR` operators.

Comment: I would like to use AND only. I am trying to see if there is a data already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify more than one condition using the `AND` or the `OR` operators.
So you can do this with a simple loop

```
$select_query = "SELECT * FROM cmd WHERE ";
$temp_array = array();
foreach($cmd_array as $key=>$val){
    $temp_string = $key ." = ".$val;
    array_push($temp_array, $temp_string);
}
$select_query .= implode(" AND ", $temp_array);
```